# Yii extract values after using Has_Many relation

Tags: yii

Relation:

```
'attendances' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Attendance', 'atd_atbs_Id')
```

Controller:

```
$report=AtbStud::model()->with('attendances')->findAll('atbs_atb_Id='.$id);
    foreach ($report->attendances as $value) {
        echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($value->atd_Date),'vardump');;
    }
```

Error:

```
"$report->attendances" Trying to get property of non-object.
```

How can we access values wen we use has_many relation.

Comment: You are using `findAll`, which results in an array being stored in `$report`. Try changing it to `find` instead.

Comment: foreach ($report as $r) foreach ($r->attendances as $value) {